# How to have scikit calculate document-term matrix from pre-tokenized documents?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have to work with pre-tokenized documents which I can load into a `list` of strings. I want to use scikit's [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.build_tokenizer) to calculate document-term matrices for them. Is this possible?

Or should I manually construct / calculate a docterm matrix myself?

The reason I want to use scikit for this, is that the above needs to be integrated into a program that's trained with scikits CountVectorizer and [BinomialNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html).

Comment: Yes you can use the CountVectorizer. But make sure to include all the terms for a sample into a single list, maybe separated by a whitespace.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Assuming I already have a CV that's fit on previous documents, what do I do to turn multiple lists (each corresponding to a document) into a doc-term matrix? Thanks

Comment: Just call transform()

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I have a `CountVectorizer cv`, a list of strings `text`, and a `MultinomialNB predictor`. If I do `dtm = cv.transform(text)` and then `prediction = predictor.predict(dtm)`, I get as many predictions as there are words in the text. It seems it's assigning a class to each word in the text. I don't want that. I have a text that I'd like to have classified as a whole (and so I expect 1 prediction). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Each element in the list you pass to transform(`text` in your case) will be used as an individual sample. If you want them to be considered single, pass them as a single string separated by whitespace inside the list, so that len(list)=1.

Comment: Vivek, the point is that I don't want pass them along as a single string separated by whitespace, because a specialized tokenizer has been written to separate this tokens previously. Thank you for your help anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code, text_list is the "list of lists" in other words text_list = [[doc1],[doc2],...,[docn]]. You can obtain a sparse matrix containing terms and their frequencies of each document in your corpus.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
TermCountsDoc = count_vect.fit_transform(text_list)   
Terms = np.array(count_vect.vocabulary_.keys())
T= TermCountsDoc.todense() #in case you need to transform it to dense matrix
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. So it's strange, this is not working for me. Scikit is complaining to me about how it expects a list of strings - not of a list of lists of strings...

I have found a different approach, however, so I'm not pursuing this avenue further.